# 80's Trilogy Title Search

Tags: story-identification

I remember this series faintly. There was a young apprentice sorcerer whose master tasks him to make a few items with specific powers. One was a chainmail that I believe made you invisible, a gold bracelet.
The master had a female visitor of some mystery. She also had an apprentice of sorts, I believe they transformed into swans?
The master's apprentice was given access to specific spells in the magic text books, and he moved the bookmark past where he was allowed to read. The apprentice's helper transcribed the spell and was killed because he read too far.
Anyone know the name of the series?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sevenwaters_Trilogy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughter_of_the_Forest?

Comment: Thanks, but no thats not it.

Comment: Suggest https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186828/book-about-a-magic-blacksmith as new duplicate target, as that has a more complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for Michael Scott Rohans Winter of the World trilogy. Book 1 is the Anvil of Ice, 2 is The Forge in the Forest and the final book is The Hammer of the Sun......then I checked on Goodreads and now have discovered that there are three more books in the series I was not previously aware of. Thanks for getting me to check.

Anyhow the hero Elof is a smith and makes a helm that allows invisibility in the first book, his 'girlfriend' kara transforms into a swan. The bit about the other apprentice being killed for forbidden knowledge fits as well.

Comment: That is perfect, this is the set and I could not remember for the life of me. I also was not aware of the additional books.

Comment: @SSword - if this is the answer you were looking for, please click the gray checkmark below the vote buttons on the top left of the answer to mark it as solved. Thanks!