# Book about a magic blacksmith

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a trilogy of books 5-10 years ago (it could have been an old story by then though) and went to recommend to a friend - but I can't for the life of my remember the author/titles.

In this world, magic and blacksmithing are linked somehow - "mastersmiths"enchant their creations while making them. There are few true "mastersmiths" who can craft in this way, and are held in high, almost god-like esteem.

What I remember:

The main protagonist is recruited by a mastersmith who teaches him the trade

> it turns out this master is a bad guy, and he was helping him build some mega-sword of super-death

Later in the story he goes into a sort of self-imposed exile, not making anything too fancy

> until someone talks him out of it? I think?

I'm hazy on the main plot details in this one, but

> near the end of the book, he forges what to modern eyes would be an iron-man suit, possibly fighting a dragon...

Can anyone help?

Comment: I will try to add more aspects as/when/if I recall them...

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but if possible could you [edit] in any more details after having a look over [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). For example, you say you read it some years ago, when was that?

Comment: I read it maybe 5-10 years ago. It may have already been an old story by then though - I got it from someone elses' bookshelves, who I sadly no longer have contact with

Comment: Check out the recommendations on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/2raglm/series_with_detailed_blacksmithing/) - does anything look familiar?

Comment: Did Dark Souls start out as a series of novels...?  If not, you could always recommend Dark Souls III for PC/console - it's good & has a magic blacksmith.  If you already made promises and can't figure it out, I'd save face & go the DS3 route...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Might be the [*Winter of the World*](http://www.users.zetnet.co.uk/mike.scott.rohan/winter/winter_index.htm) series by Mike Scott Rohan (no relation). The hero certainly becomes a master smith, and leaves the land of his birth.

> Chiefest among the Chronicles is the tale of Elof, who rose from a
>   nameless foundling and serf to become a magesmith of ever-increasing
>   art and power; and of the great skill, great knowledge, great love and
>   great folly of which his life was shaped, and the awesome deeds he
>   accomplished. How at first he fell into evil, was cleansed and, with
>   the aid of his fast friends and the strange figures who haunted him,
>   undid his ill-doing; how with those friends he sought a new home for
>   his people across the breadth of a continent, and found that in his
>   quest he was also pursuing the girl he had long loved, bond-servant of
>   the Powers of Ice; and how he lost her once more, and went seeking her
>   across the wide oceans of the world to the ancient home of
>   civilization, and there found the destiny of the world in the balance;
>   of these the first three books tell. And of how he won at last the
>   name of Elof Valantor, Elof of the Skilled Hand, mightiest of all
>   magesmiths amid the dark days of the Winter of the World.

Comment: Yes, that's the one! I see there are more in the series than I've read, so that's something to add to my reading list too =]